# Powershell script to print image

Tags: .net, powershell

I wrote this powershell script to print images. But when the script runs and starts to print I am getting empty page printout. I tried to use [printdocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printdocument?view=netframework-4.8) and [graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=netframework-4.8) from .NET framework.This is my first time using powershell and .NET framework so I used this scripts for reference: [script1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RoughDraft/0.1/Content/Send-Printer.ps1), [script2](http://monadblog.blogspot.com/2006/02/msh-print-image.html). I don't know what I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```bsh
function Start-Print {

    $CopyCount = 1

    $pd = New-Object System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\Users\Phuntsho Wangdi\Desktop\New folder\unprinted\*" -Include "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.jpg"

    foreach ($global:file in $files) {

        $file_name = Get-ChildItem -Name $file

        Write-Host $file_name

        $pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Canon E510 series printer"
        $pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = $True
        $pd.PrinterSettings.Copies = $CopyCount
        $pd.DefaultPageSettings.Color = $false
        $pd.DocumentName = $file_name

        $action = {
            $bmp = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap("$file")

            #implemented from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RoughDraft/0.1/Content/Send-Printer.ps1
            $newWidth = $bmp.Width * 100 / $bmp.HorizontalResolution
            $newHeight = $bmp.height * 100 / $bmp.VerticalResolution

            $widthFactor = $newWidth / $EventArgs.PageSettings.PrintableArea.height
            $HeightFactor = $newHeight / $EventArgs.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Width

            $widthMargin = 0
            $heightMargin = 0

            if ($widthFactor -ge 1 -or $HeightFactor -ge 1) {
                if ($widthFactor -gt $HeightFactor) {
                    $newWidth = $newWidth / $widthFactor 
                    $newHeight = $newHeight / $widthFactor 

                }
                else {
                    $newWidth = $newWidth / $HeightFactor
                    $newHeight = $newHeight / $HeightFactor

                }               
            }

            $heightMargin = (($EventArgs.PageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - $newHeight) / 2) / 2

            $EventArgs.Graphics.DrawImage($bmp, ($EventArgs.PageSetting.HardMarginX + $widthMargin), ($EventArgs.PageSetting.HardMarginY + $heightMargin), $newWidth, $newHeight)
        }

        $endprint = {
            $bmp.Dispose()
        }

        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $pd -EventName "PrintPage" -Action $action
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $pd -EventName "EndPrint" -Action $endprint

        $pd.Print()
    }
    Write-Host "Done!"   
}
```

Comment: Is `Start-Process .\123.jpg -Verb Print` not suitable for your puropses?

Comment: I've tried that but it opens a window to set paper size, paper type...etc. But I want to print image without having any user intervention.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?